# no code is downloaded after executing a git fetch

Tags: git, command-line, github

I'm trying to use [hub](http://chriswanstrath.com/hub/) in combination with git.
**Note:** hub simplifies git usage when you host your code on github.

When I do a fetch it looks like the repository is fetched:

```
udos@X100e:/var/www/mantisbt$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 54427, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9435/9435), done.
remote: Total 54427 (delta 44510), reused 54427 (delta 44510)
Receiving objects: 100% (54427/54427), 19.20 MiB | 395 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (44510/44510), done.
From github.com:udos/mantisbt
 * [new branch]      manzen     -> origin/manzen
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      votes_refactor -> origin/votes_refactor
 * [new tag]         manzen_first_working_prototype -> manzen_first_working_prototype
```

But when taking a look at the directory, it's not there:

```
udos@X100e:/var/www/mantisbt$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 udos udos 4096 2011-02-12 23:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 2011-02-12 21:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 udos udos 4096 2011-02-12 23:02 .git
```

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with hub.. but what branch are you in?

Comment: in none, because no code was fetched... git br returns no branch...

Comment: Doesn't git fetch just update your copies of the remote branches (I've been using mercurial for a while and the commands are the opposite pull is fetch and fetch is pull..)?

Comment: git pull is combining git fetch and git merge into one command and gives the same result as executing them sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Fetch does indeed download objects and refs. The trick is that they are hidden.

A simple

```
udos@X100e:/var/www/mantisbt$ git branch
```

returns nothing.

Instead

```
udos@X100e:/var/www/mantisbt$ git branch -a
  remotes/origin/manzen
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/votes_refactor
```

shows the "hidden" branches.

Checking them out and making them "visible" is done using (regular) command

```
udos@X100e:/var/www/mantisbt$ git checkout manzen
Branch manzen set up to track remote branch manzen from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'manzen'
```

After this, the branch is "visible" again:

```
udos@X100e:/var/www/mantisbt$ git branch
* manzen
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch only downloads the changes from the remote, to apply the upstream changes changes use pull or merge.  If you're starting from scratch, perhaps you want to clone the repo first though?

Comment: sure about this? git help sais this "fetch - Download objects and refs from another repository"